# subl . command not working on terminal

Tags: linux, macos, sublimetext

I was trying to open my first app on ionic on sublime text using sublime text. It gave me a "command not found" error. How to fix?

I tried those commands:

1. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl`
2. `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin`

Comment: What sublime version did you install 2 or 3?

Comment: its Sublime text 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying the binary rather than symlinking it.

`cp /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

You can verify that it's been installed by running `which subl` - the output should be `/usr/local/bin/subl`.

Comment: Yes it's already installed. i have been using sublime for other text editing like html,c++ etc. I need to open the ionic directory in sublime.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ionic, but would think that if the `subl` binary is installed, then `subl path/to/ionic/directory` should open that directory in Sublime Text. If you already have Sublime Text open, try quitting the program then running `subl path/to/ionic/directory`.

Comment: Thank you! i figured it out. Error was in line 2. cp /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl . it should to be rewrite as cp /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl.

Comment: Thanks! This is straightforward and works. Don't know why it was downvoted.